# As the first player, can I choose whether to perform a Special Activity after completing my Operation?

Tags: cuba-libre

When I'm the first player on a card in Cuba Libre, can I perform my Operation before deciding whether to perform a Special Activity or not? The distinction is important because the desirability (and even possibility) of certain Special Activities can vary based on the die roll(s) of an operation. Also, one might desire to see their operation through before deciding to Launder (which is only possible without Special Activity), particularly if depending on another player's Cash to Launder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules as written of Cube Libre have no say in whether the Special Activities must be declared beforehand. The turn track is adjusted after the player completes its activities so it can be deduced that the player can choose to add a Special Activity if the rest of the involved rules are respected.

I have played several COIN games and only Pendragon comes to mind in that all Operations and Special Activites (Feats in that game) must be declared and marked on the map before executing any action.